# Mock for loop with interface

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I have this java code who include interface.

```
ILocation<ILocation> contactLocations = fileSystem.getContactLocations();
for (ILocation location : contactLocations) {
    location.getType();
    ...
}

public interface ILocation{
    String getName();
    ...
}

public interface ILocationS<T extends ILocation> extends IListCollectionWrapper<T> {
    ...
}

public abstract interface IListCollectionWrapper<E>extends ICollectionWrapper<E>{
    public abstract List<E> getAsList();
}

ILocation<ILocation> contactLocations = fileSystem.getContactLocations();
for (ILocation locations : contactLocations) {
    ...
}
```

I use Mockito and i try to test the content of the for loop.

```
Iterator<ILocation> mockIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
Mockito.when(locations.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);

Mockito.when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(location);

Mockito.when(location.getType()).thenReturn("test");
```

I never enter de for loop

Comment: Did you write your own iterator? If so could you share that code? If not, could you mock `fileSystem.getContactLocations()` to return a proper `ILocation` object so you don't have to mock the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly mocked Iterator's other important method, `hasNext`. By default Mockito will return `false` for all boolean-typed methods, so `hasNext` will always be false and you'll never enter the for loop.

This is an excellent reason not to mock data objects like most Iterables; use the real thing, or create a `new ArrayList<ILocation>`, populate it, and have your mock return `yourArrayList.iterator()`.